# Access route parameters without promise Angular 6

Tags: angular, service, observable, resolver

I'm using Angular 6. When i want to use route parameters, I use this code:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    // use params now as a object variable
});
```

But I need to use parameters in service calling. Example I have a service for getting user info.  And I call this service inside of resolver. If I want to use subscribe, I can not return service result:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        return this.FixturesService.getFixtures(params);
    });    
});
```

It's not working now. It says:

> A function whose declared type in neither 'void' nor 'any' must return
>   a value.

How can I return service result, inside of the resolve function with passing route parameters to the service that I called and return it to component?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using `switchMap` to change your route params observable to the observable of your service:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
  return route.params.switchMap(params => this.FixturesService.getFixtures(params));
}
```

The service call will not be made until the params are resolved, and then subscribers will receive the result of the service call.

Thanks to @JBNizet for the correction.

Comment: If this.FixturesService.getFixtures() returns an Observable, it should in fact be switchMap(), not map(). And, @Sami, Don't use `any`. Use the correct type of the data that the service is returning.

Comment: I tried map and switchMap but  did not work. Same error: **vendor.js:32791 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: route.params.switchMap is not a function
TypeError: route.params.switchMap is not a function**

Comment: @JBNizet What type should I use for objects?

Comment: You may need to import the operator for `switchMap`, but that might have changed in Angular 6 and I don't know on hand what is the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: Actually, route here is of type ActivatedRouteSnapshot, not ActivatedRoute. So the params are accessible directly. `return this.FixturesService.getFixtures(route.params)`. https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot#params

Comment: But I have another problem. I'm using resolver and service for binding data before loading the route completely for angular universal. I want to bind XHR data to view when I try to open "view source" version in angular universal.